# axios.create({MY Conig}) raise error (config is undefined)

Tags: javascript, axios

In Windows 10, I'm using `react-router-dom` 5.2.0 and `react-redux` 7.2.5 and `react` 17.0.2 and `axios` 0.21.4 and WebStorm 2023.1.3 IDE.

axiosInstance.js:

```
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { updateAccessToken } from '../actions/userActions';

const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';

export const axiosInstance = (userInfo, dispatch) => {
    const instance = axios.create({
        'mode': 'cors',
        baseURL: baseURL,
        headers:  {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo?.access}`,
        }
    });

    instance.interceptors.request.use(async (req) => {
            const user = jwt_decode(userInfo.access);
            const isExpired = dayjs.unix(user.exp).diff(dayjs()) < 5000;
            if (!(isExpired)) {
                return req
            }

            const response = await axios.post(
                '/api/v1/users/token/refresh/', { refresh: userInfo.refresh },
            );


            dispatch(updateAccessToken(response.data))
            req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${response.data.access}`;
            return req;
    });
    return instance
}
```

userActions.js:

```js
export const  getUserDetailsAction = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_DETAILS_REQUEST
        });
        const { userLogin: { userInfo } } = getState();

        const authRequestAxios = axiosInstance(userInfo, dispatch)
        const { data } = await authRequestAxios.get(`/api/v1/users/${userInfo._id}/`);
        dispatch({
            type: USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
            payload: data,
        });
        localStorage.setItem('userDetails', JSON.stringify(data));
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ // USER FURTHER INFORMATION FAILED
            type: USER_DETAILS_FAILED,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.detail ? error.response.data.detail : error.message,
        });
    }
```

error IDE:

Argument type `{mode: string, headers: {Authorization: string, "Content-Type": string}, baseURL: string}` is not assignable to parameter type* AxiosRequestConfig | undefined *  Object literal may only specify known properties, but the following are `extra: 'mode'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Please run the code after removing the mode property from the configuration object, because it is not a valid Axios configuration option and import like this "import axios from 'axios';,
import { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';"*